# A Soft body (Nurbs Circle curve) collides with a Plane but doesn't do it with Cube & other objects

Tags: objects, bezier-curves, collision, soft-body

The case is this:

A soft body (Nurbs Circle curve) falls on the floor and on one more object. The floor is a Plane mesh, the object is a Cube mesh. Collision physics is enabled for both. The soft body collides with the plane, but goes trough the cube. Somebody advised me to increase curve subdivision for achieving collision with the Cube but it did not help. The Cube is not parented. No other modifiers are applied.

Please advise how to resolve this issue!

Thank you.

Regards,

Peter

Comment: I don't think physics work well on non mesh objects, convert a copy of it to mesh and see if it improves.

Comment: I don't understand this question - Blender won't let me add Soft Body to a Nurbs object. Please clarify - upload a sample Blend file if possible.

Comment: @RichSedman, yes, Blender allows adding Soft Body to a Nurbs Circle via Physics. And the question is: Why it does not collide with a Cube while collides with a Plane when Collision is enabled for both? As to uploading a sample Blender file - I don't see such an option, so I'll appreciate if you advise me how to do it.
Thanks.
Regards.

Comment: @Peter Quite right - I think I must have been trying it on a Nurbs Surface instead of a Nurbs Curve. Just tried again and they can indeed have soft body. For uploading blend files, see https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ - you can use that to upload your Blend file and this will provide a link that you can paste into your question.

Comment: @Peter - I've managed to replicate this using both a Cube and a Plane - if the soft body nurbs circle falls close to the edge of either then it does not collide properly. However, converting the Nurbs paths to mesh and re-applying Soft Body (since the conversion loses the soft body modifier) and the collision works as it would be expected. This appears to me to potentially be a bug with soft body when acting on Nurbs objects.